# Play 2.4 and Guice Module, how can I re-use what I have now?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I am upgrading to Playframework 2.4 and I have this currently:

`Global.scala`:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings with LazzyLogging {
  private lazy val injector = {
    Guice.createInjector(new ServiceModule)
  }
}

override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]): A = {
    injector.getInstance(controllerClass)
  }
```

`ServiesModule.scala`:

```
class ServicesModule extends ScalaModule {
  def configure() {
    bind[userService].to[UserServiceImpl]
    ...
    .
  }
}
```

I am not getting a compile error:

```
Global.scala:28: method getControllerInstance overrides nothing
[error]   override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]): A = {
```

My routes file has this for dependancy injected routes:

```
GET /abc         @controller.HomeController.index
```

What do I have to change, I hope I can re-use my `ServicesModule` but it is using the [sse-guice library](https://github.com/sptz45/sse-guice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you show in your question, you have to change a small amount of things:

1. Start to use [injected routes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting#Dependency-Injection) so that you can have DI in your controllers. Just add the following line to your `build.sbt` file:

   routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

This will also requires that you change your `routes` file to remove `@` from routes declarations. So, your route will be:

```
GET /abc         controller.HomeController.index
```

2. Provide [custom binding](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Providing-custom-bindings) to your `ServiceModule` using `play.modules.enabled` configuration. To do that, just add the following line to your `application.conf`:

   play.modules.enabled += "com.acme.services.ServiceModule"

You may need to change your `ServiceModule` to extends `AbstractModule` instead of `ScalaModule`:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

class ServicesModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() {
    bind[userService].to[UserServiceImpl]
  }
}
```

3. [Remove your `GlobalSettings`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings) in favor of new way to do things.

Also, I recommend that you read the [Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24). It is full with information about how you can adapt your code.